# Cannot run artisan command in Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, homestead, laravel-artisan

After setting up Homestead [for 1 specific project only](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead#per-project-installation), I want to run the Artisan CLI for database migrations. I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart#database-migrations) and I keep getting this error:

```
Could not open input file: artisan
```

I set up the project by running these commands (Windows):

```
composer require laravel/homestead --dev
vendor\\bin\\homestead make
vagrant up
```

And then I made sure to be in the root project directory and then run `php artisan list`, which gives the error above.

I also tried to ssh into the Homestead VM and navigated to the `code` folder (where my project resides) and run `php artisan list`, to which it gives the same error.

Attached is my working directory where I run the artisan command, as requested:

[image: working directory]

I have tried running it in root dir and in `vendor\\laravel` to no avail.

So how would one run the artisan CLI in a Laravel Homestead project?

Comment: In  your Code directory you have "node_module" directory.

Comment: @Vipul I do not see it anywhere in my code directory. Could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: can you share which directory are exist in "code" directory. i think you are not in project directory

Comment: @Vipul I've shared my working directory, thanks.

Comment: You need to go in laravel/homestead directory and try the command

Comment: have you tried running it under the laundry-system directory?

Comment: @kapitan yup. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. The problem was that I haven't set up a Laravel project using `composer` yet, and skipped to install Laravel Homestead for this project.

So to make a Laravel project named e.g. `quickstart`, one should first *create* the project by running

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel quickstart --prefer-dist
```

(see https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart#installation for more details)

Only after that, set up homestead for the project by running

```
composer require laravel/homestead --dev
vendor\bin\homestead make
```

And now the project should be fully initialized.

Refs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead#per-project-installation